# Playing specific sounds when an object is revealed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, puzzle, card, soundeffect

I have completed a tutorial on how to make a memory card, everything works great, I can play the game and match all the cards (20 or 30 or 40 for different categories cause I have 6 of them) and I added a timer. I can even reset the game and start all over, and all the cards are randomly sorted out.

But I want to go beyond the tutorial and put some sound effects in the game to make it more fun. I get that you can play sounds on mouse clicks and stuff, but I want to play sounds when specific cards are revealed. Duck card appears and you hear a quacking sound or his name. I'm a beginner and I don't know how to add it.

I'm not sure if I would start a new C# script or add to my existing (PictureManager) script or (Picture) script.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. These are my (PictureManager) and (Picture) script for the game.

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;


public class PictureManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Picture PicturePrefab;

    public Transform PicSpawnPosition;

    public Vector2 StartPosition = new Vector2(-2.15f, 3.62f);

    public AudioSource WinSound;

    public AudioSource BgSound;


    [Space]
    [Header("End Game Screen")]
    public GameObject EndGamePanel;
    public GameObject NewBestScoreText;
    public GameObject YourScoreText;
    public GameObject EndTimeText;

    /*to rremove
    public List<AudioClip> Vegetabels = new List<AudioClip>();
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    to remove*/

    public enum GameState
    { 
       NoAction,
       MovingOnPositions,
       DeletingPuzzles,
       FlipBack,
       Checking,
       GameEnd
    };

    public enum PuzzleState
    {
        PuzzleRotating,
        CanRotate,
    };

    public enum RevealedState
    {
        NoRevealed,
        OneRevealed,
        TwoRevealed
    };

    [HideInInspector]
    public GameState CurrentGameState;
    [HideInInspector]
    public PuzzleState CurrentPuzzleState;
    [HideInInspector]
    public RevealedState PuzzleRevealedNumber;


    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Picture> PictureList;

    private Vector2 _offset = new Vector2(1.42f, 1.52f);
    private Vector2 _offsetFor15Pairs = new Vector2(1.08f, 1.22f);
    private Vector2 _offsetFor20Pairs = new Vector2(1.08f, 1.0f);
    private Vector3 _newScaleDown = new Vector3(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.001f);

    private List<Material> _materialList = new List<Material>();
    private List<string> _texturePathList = new List<string>();
    private Material _firstMaterial;
    private string _firstTexturePath;

    private int _firstRevealedPic;
    private int _secondRevealedPic;
    private int _revealedPicNumber = 0;
    private int _picToDestroy1;
    private int _picToDestroy2;

    private bool _corutineStarted = false;

    private int _pairNumbers;
    private int _removedPairs;
    private Timer _gameTimer;
    void Start()
    {
        //BgSound.Play();
        CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;
        CurrentPuzzleState = PuzzleState.CanRotate;
        PuzzleRevealedNumber = RevealedState.NoRevealed;
        _revealedPicNumber = 0;
        _firstRevealedPic = -1;
        _secondRevealedPic = -1;

        _removedPairs = 0;
        _pairNumbers = (int)GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber();

        _gameTimer = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Timer>();

        LoadMaterials();

        if(GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber()== GameSettings.EPairNumber.E10Pairs)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MovingOnPositions;
            SpwanPictureMesh(4, 5, StartPosition, _offset, false);
            MovePicture(4, 5, StartPosition, _offset);
        }
        else if (GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber() == GameSettings.EPairNumber.E15Pairs)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MovingOnPositions;
            SpwanPictureMesh(5, 6, StartPosition, _offset, false);
            MovePicture(5, 6, StartPosition, _offsetFor15Pairs);
        }
        else if (GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber() == GameSettings.EPairNumber.E20Pairs)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MovingOnPositions;
            SpwanPictureMesh(5, 8, StartPosition, _offset, true);
            MovePicture(5, 8, StartPosition, _offsetFor20Pairs);
        }
    }

    public void CheckPicture()
    {
        CurrentGameState = GameState.Checking;
        _revealedPicNumber = 0;

        for(int id = 0; id < PictureList.Count; id++)
        {
            if(PictureList[id].Revealed && _revealedPicNumber < 2)
            {
                if(_revealedPicNumber == 0)
                {
                    _firstRevealedPic = id;
                    _revealedPicNumber++;
                    //audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id]);
                }
                else if (_revealedPicNumber == 1)
                {
                    _secondRevealedPic = id;
                    _revealedPicNumber++;
                }
            }
            if (_revealedPicNumber == 2)
            {
                if (PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].GetIndex() == PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].GetIndex() && _firstRevealedPic != _secondRevealedPic)
                {
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.DeletingPuzzles;
                    _picToDestroy1 = _firstRevealedPic;
                    _picToDestroy2 = _secondRevealedPic;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.FlipBack;
                }
            }
        }

        
        CurrentPuzzleState = PictureManager.PuzzleState.CanRotate;

        if(CurrentGameState == GameState.Checking)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;
        }
    }

    private void DestroyPicture()
    {
        PuzzleRevealedNumber = RevealedState.NoRevealed;
        PictureList[_picToDestroy1].Deactivate();
        PictureList[_picToDestroy2].Deactivate();
        _revealedPicNumber = 0;
        _removedPairs++;
        CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;
        CurrentPuzzleState = PuzzleState.CanRotate;
    }

    private IEnumerator FlipBack()
    {
        _corutineStarted = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].FlipBack();
        PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].FlipBack();

        PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].Revealed = false;
        PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].Revealed = false;

        PuzzleRevealedNumber = RevealedState.NoRevealed;
        CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;

        _corutineStarted = false;
    }

    private void LoadMaterials()
    {
        var materialFilePath = GameSettings.Instance.GetMaterialDirectoryName();
        var textureFilePath = GameSettings.Instance.GetPuzzleCategoryTextureDirectoryName();
        var pairNumber = (int)GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber();
        const string matBaseName = "Pic";
        var firstMaterialName = "Back";

        for(var index = 1; index <= pairNumber; index++)
        {
            var currentFilePath = materialFilePath + matBaseName + index;
            Material mat = Resources.Load(currentFilePath, typeof(Material)) as Material;
            _materialList.Add(mat);

            var currentTextureFilePath = textureFilePath + matBaseName + index;
            _texturePathList.Add(currentTextureFilePath);
        }
        _firstTexturePath = textureFilePath + firstMaterialName;
        _firstMaterial = Resources.Load(materialFilePath + firstMaterialName, typeof(Material)) as Material;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (PauseMenu.isPaused == false) {
        if (CurrentGameState == GameState.DeletingPuzzles)
        {
            if(CurrentPuzzleState == PuzzleState.CanRotate)
            {
                DestroyPicture();
                CheckGameEnd();
            }
        }
        if (CurrentGameState == GameState.FlipBack)
        {
            if(CurrentPuzzleState == PuzzleState.CanRotate && _corutineStarted == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FlipBack());
            }
        }

        if(CurrentGameState == GameState.GameEnd)
        {
            if(PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].gameObject.activeSelf == false &&
                PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].gameObject.activeSelf == false &&
                EndGamePanel.activeSelf == false)
            {
                ShowEndGameInformation();
                if (GameSettings.Instance.IsSoundEffectMutedPermanently() == false)
                        WinSound.Play();
                //BgSound.Pause();
            }
        }
        }
    }

    private bool CheckGameEnd()
    {
        if(_removedPairs == _pairNumbers && CurrentGameState != GameState.GameEnd)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.GameEnd;
            _gameTimer.StopTimer();
            Config.PlaceScoreOnBorad(_gameTimer.GetCurrentTime());
        }
        return (CurrentGameState == GameState.GameEnd);
    }
    private void ShowEndGameInformation()
    {
        EndGamePanel.SetActive(true);

        if(Config.IsBestScore())
        {
            NewBestScoreText.SetActive(true);
            YourScoreText.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            NewBestScoreText.SetActive(false);
            YourScoreText.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        var timer = _gameTimer.GetCurrentTime();
        var minutes = Mathf.Floor(timer / 60);
        var seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(timer % 60);
        var newText = minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
        EndTimeText.GetComponent<Text>().text = newText;
    }

    private void SpwanPictureMesh(int rows, int columns, Vector2 Pos, Vector2 offset, bool scaleDown)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                var tempPicture = (Picture)Instantiate(PicturePrefab, PicSpawnPosition.position, PicturePrefab.transform.rotation);

                if(scaleDown)
                {
                    tempPicture.transform.localScale = _newScaleDown;
                }

                tempPicture.name = tempPicture.name + 'c' + col + 'r' + row;
                PictureList.Add(tempPicture);
            }
        }
        ApplyTextures();
    }

    public void ApplyTextures()
    {
        var rndMatIndex = Random.Range(0, _materialList.Count);
        var AppliedTimes = new int[_materialList.Count];

        for(int i = 0; i< _materialList.Count; i++)
        {
            AppliedTimes[i] = 0;
        }

        foreach(var o in PictureList)
        {
            var randPrevious = rndMatIndex;
            var counter = 0;
            var forceMat = false;

            while(AppliedTimes[rndMatIndex] >= 2 || ((randPrevious == rndMatIndex) && !forceMat))
            {
                rndMatIndex = Random.Range(0, _materialList.Count);
                counter++;
                if(counter > 100)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < _materialList.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if(AppliedTimes[j] < 2)
                        {
                            rndMatIndex = j;
                            forceMat = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (forceMat == false)
                        return;
                }

            }

            o.SetFirstMaterial(_firstMaterial, _firstTexturePath);
            o.ApplyFirstMaterial();
            o.SetSecondMaterial(_materialList[rndMatIndex], _texturePathList[rndMatIndex]);
            o.SetIndex(rndMatIndex);
            o.Revealed = false;
            AppliedTimes[rndMatIndex] += 1;
            forceMat = false;
        }


    }

    private void MovePicture(int rows, int columns, Vector2 pos, Vector2 offset)
    {
        var index = 0;
        for(var col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                var targetPosition = new Vector3((pos.x + (offset.x * row)), (pos.y - (offset.y * col)), 0.0f);
                StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(targetPosition, PictureList[index]));
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Vector3 target, Picture obj)
    {
        var randomDis = 7;

        while(obj.transform.position !=target)
        {
            obj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(obj.transform.position, target, randomDis * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return 0;
        }
    }

}

----------------------------------------------

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Picture : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip PressSound;
    private Material _firstMaterial;
    private Material _secondMaterial;

    private Quaternion _currentRotation;

    [HideInInspector] public bool Revealed = false;
    private PictureManager _pictureManager;
    private bool _clicked = false;
    private int _index;

    private AudioSource _audio;
    public void SetIndex(int id)
    {
        _index = id;
    }
    
    public int GetIndex()
    {
        return _index;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Revealed = false;
        _clicked = false;
        _pictureManager = GameObject.Find("[PictureManager]").GetComponent<PictureManager>();
        _currentRotation = gameObject.transform.rotation;

        _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        _audio.clip = PressSound;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(_clicked == false)
        {
            if (PauseMenu.isPaused == false)
            {
                _pictureManager.CurrentPuzzleState = PictureManager.PuzzleState.PuzzleRotating;
                if (GameSettings.Instance.IsSoundEffectMutedPermanently() == false)
                    _audio.Play();
                StartCoroutine(LoopRotation(45, false));
                _clicked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void FlipBack()
    {
        if (gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            _pictureManager.CurrentPuzzleState = PictureManager.PuzzleState.PuzzleRotating;
            Revealed = false;
            /*if (GameSettings.Instance.IsSoundEffectMutedPermanently() == false)
                _audio.Play();*/
            StartCoroutine(LoopRotation(45, true));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoopRotation(float angle, bool FirstMat)
    {
        var rot = 0f;
        const float dir = 1f;
        const float rotSpeed = 180.0f;
        const float rotSpeed1 = 90.0f;
        var startAngle = angle;
        var assigned = false;

        if(FirstMat)
        {
            while(rot < angle)
            {
                var step = Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed1;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0) * step * dir);
                if(rot >= (startAngle - 2) && assigned == false)
                {
                    ApplyFirstMaterial();
                    assigned = true;
                }
                rot += (1 * step * dir);
                yield return null;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            while (angle > 0)
            {
                float step = Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0) * step * dir);
                angle -= (1 * step * dir);
                yield return null;
            }
        }
        gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().rotation = _currentRotation;

        if (!FirstMat)
        {
            Revealed = true;
            ApplySecondMaterial();
            _pictureManager.CheckPicture();
        }
        else
        {
            _pictureManager.PuzzleRevealedNumber = PictureManager.RevealedState.NoRevealed;
            _pictureManager.CurrentPuzzleState = PictureManager.PuzzleState.CanRotate;
        }

        _clicked = false;

    }

    public void SetFirstMaterial(Material mat, string texturePath)
    {
        _firstMaterial = mat;
        _firstMaterial.mainTexture = Resources.Load(texturePath, typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
    }

    public void SetSecondMaterial(Material mat, string texturePath)
    {
        _secondMaterial = mat;
        _secondMaterial.mainTexture = Resources.Load(texturePath, typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
    }

    public void ApplyFirstMaterial()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = _firstMaterial;
    }

    public void ApplySecondMaterial()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = _secondMaterial;
    }
    public void Deactivate()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DeactivateCorutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator DeactivateCorutine()
    {
        Revealed = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PictureManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Picture PicturePrefab;
    public Transform PicSpawnPosition;
    public Vector2 StartPosition = new Vector2(-2.15f, 3.62f);
    public AudioSource WinSound;
    public AudioSource BgSound;

    [Space]
    [Header("End Game Screen")]
    public GameObject EndGamePanel;
    public GameObject NewBestScoreText;
    public GameObject YourScoreText;
    public GameObject EndTimeText;

    /*to rremove
    public List<AudioClip> Vegetabels = new List<AudioClip>();
    private AudioSource audioSource;
    to remove*/

    public enum GameState
    { 
       NoAction,
       MovingOnPositions,
       DeletingPuzzles,
       FlipBack,
       Checking,
       GameEnd
    };

    public enum PuzzleState
    {
        PuzzleRotating,
        CanRotate,
    };

    public enum RevealedState
    {
        NoRevealed,
        OneRevealed,
        TwoRevealed
    };

    [HideInInspector]
    public GameState CurrentGameState;
    [HideInInspector]
    public PuzzleState CurrentPuzzleState;
    [HideInInspector]
    public RevealedState PuzzleRevealedNumber;


    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Picture> PictureList;

    private Vector2 _offset = new Vector2(1.42f, 1.52f);
    private Vector2 _offsetFor15Pairs = new Vector2(1.08f, 1.22f);
    private Vector2 _offsetFor20Pairs = new Vector2(1.08f, 1.0f);
    private Vector3 _newScaleDown = new Vector3(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.001f);

    private List<Material> _materialList = new List<Material>();
    private List<string> _texturePathList = new List<string>();
    private Material _firstMaterial;
    private string _firstTexturePath;

    private int _firstRevealedPic;
    private int _secondRevealedPic;
    private int _revealedPicNumber = 0;
    private int _picToDestroy1;
    private int _picToDestroy2;

    private bool _corutineStarted = false;

    private int _pairNumbers;
    private int _removedPairs;
    private Timer _gameTimer;
    void Start()
    {
        //BgSound.Play();
        CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;
        CurrentPuzzleState = PuzzleState.CanRotate;
        PuzzleRevealedNumber = RevealedState.NoRevealed;
        _revealedPicNumber = 0;
        _firstRevealedPic = -1;
        _secondRevealedPic = -1;

        _removedPairs = 0;
        _pairNumbers = (int)GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber();

        _gameTimer = GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<Timer>();

        LoadMaterials();

        if(GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber()== GameSettings.EPairNumber.E10Pairs)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MovingOnPositions;
            SpwanPictureMesh(4, 5, StartPosition, _offset, false);
            MovePicture(4, 5, StartPosition, _offset);
        }
        else if (GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber() == GameSettings.EPairNumber.E15Pairs)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MovingOnPositions;
            SpwanPictureMesh(5, 6, StartPosition, _offset, false);
            MovePicture(5, 6, StartPosition, _offsetFor15Pairs);
        }
        else if (GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber() == GameSettings.EPairNumber.E20Pairs)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.MovingOnPositions;
            SpwanPictureMesh(5, 8, StartPosition, _offset, true);
            MovePicture(5, 8, StartPosition, _offsetFor20Pairs);
        }
    }

    public void CheckPicture()
    {
        CurrentGameState = GameState.Checking;
        _revealedPicNumber = 0;

        for(int id = 0; id < PictureList.Count; id++)
        {
            if(PictureList[id].Revealed && _revealedPicNumber < 2)
            {
                if(_revealedPicNumber == 0)
                {
                    _firstRevealedPic = id;
                    _revealedPicNumber++;
                    //audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id]);
                }
                else if (_revealedPicNumber == 1)
                {
                    _secondRevealedPic = id;
                    _revealedPicNumber++;
                }
            }
            if (_revealedPicNumber == 2)
            {
                if (PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].GetIndex() == PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].GetIndex() && _firstRevealedPic != _secondRevealedPic)
                {
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.DeletingPuzzles;
                    _picToDestroy1 = _firstRevealedPic;
                    _picToDestroy2 = _secondRevealedPic;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.FlipBack;
                }
            }
        }

        
        CurrentPuzzleState = PictureManager.PuzzleState.CanRotate;

        if(CurrentGameState == GameState.Checking)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;
        }
    }

    private void DestroyPicture()
    {
        PuzzleRevealedNumber = RevealedState.NoRevealed;
        PictureList[_picToDestroy1].Deactivate();
        PictureList[_picToDestroy2].Deactivate();
        _revealedPicNumber = 0;
        _removedPairs++;
        CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;
        CurrentPuzzleState = PuzzleState.CanRotate;
    }

    private IEnumerator FlipBack()
    {
        _corutineStarted = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].FlipBack();
        PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].FlipBack();

        PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].Revealed = false;
        PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].Revealed = false;

        PuzzleRevealedNumber = RevealedState.NoRevealed;
        CurrentGameState = GameState.NoAction;

        _corutineStarted = false;
    }

    private void LoadMaterials()
    {
        var materialFilePath = GameSettings.Instance.GetMaterialDirectoryName();
        var textureFilePath = GameSettings.Instance.GetPuzzleCategoryTextureDirectoryName();
        var pairNumber = (int)GameSettings.Instance.GetPairNumber();
        const string matBaseName = "Pic";
        var firstMaterialName = "Back";

        for(var index = 1; index <= pairNumber; index++)
        {
            var currentFilePath = materialFilePath + matBaseName + index;
            Material mat = Resources.Load(currentFilePath, typeof(Material)) as Material;
            _materialList.Add(mat);

            var currentTextureFilePath = textureFilePath + matBaseName + index;
            _texturePathList.Add(currentTextureFilePath);
        }
        _firstTexturePath = textureFilePath + firstMaterialName;
        _firstMaterial = Resources.Load(materialFilePath + firstMaterialName, typeof(Material)) as Material;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (PauseMenu.isPaused == false) {
        if (CurrentGameState == GameState.DeletingPuzzles)
        {
            if(CurrentPuzzleState == PuzzleState.CanRotate)
            {
                DestroyPicture();
                CheckGameEnd();
            }
        }
        if (CurrentGameState == GameState.FlipBack)
        {
            if(CurrentPuzzleState == PuzzleState.CanRotate && _corutineStarted == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine(FlipBack());
            }
        }

        if(CurrentGameState == GameState.GameEnd)
        {
            if(PictureList[_firstRevealedPic].gameObject.activeSelf == false &&
                PictureList[_secondRevealedPic].gameObject.activeSelf == false &&
                EndGamePanel.activeSelf == false)
            {
                ShowEndGameInformation();
                if (GameSettings.Instance.IsSoundEffectMutedPermanently() == false)
                        WinSound.Play();
                //BgSound.Pause();
            }
        }
        }
    }

    private bool CheckGameEnd()
    {
        if(_removedPairs == _pairNumbers && CurrentGameState != GameState.GameEnd)
        {
            CurrentGameState = GameState.GameEnd;
            _gameTimer.StopTimer();
            Config.PlaceScoreOnBorad(_gameTimer.GetCurrentTime());
        }
        return (CurrentGameState == GameState.GameEnd);
    }
    private void ShowEndGameInformation()
    {
        EndGamePanel.SetActive(true);

        if(Config.IsBestScore())
        {
            NewBestScoreText.SetActive(true);
            YourScoreText.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            NewBestScoreText.SetActive(false);
            YourScoreText.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        var timer = _gameTimer.GetCurrentTime();
        var minutes = Mathf.Floor(timer / 60);
        var seconds = Mathf.RoundToInt(timer % 60);
        var newText = minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
        EndTimeText.GetComponent<Text>().text = newText;
    }

    private void SpwanPictureMesh(int rows, int columns, Vector2 Pos, Vector2 offset, bool scaleDown)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                var tempPicture = (Picture)Instantiate(PicturePrefab, PicSpawnPosition.position, PicturePrefab.transform.rotation);

                if(scaleDown)
                {
                    tempPicture.transform.localScale = _newScaleDown;
                }

                tempPicture.name = tempPicture.name + 'c' + col + 'r' + row;
                PictureList.Add(tempPicture);
            }
        }
        ApplyTextures();
    }

    public void ApplyTextures()
    {
        var rndMatIndex = Random.Range(0, _materialList.Count);
        var AppliedTimes = new int[_materialList.Count];

        for(int i = 0; i< _materialList.Count; i++)
        {
            AppliedTimes[i] = 0;
        }

        foreach(var o in PictureList)
        {
            var randPrevious = rndMatIndex;
            var counter = 0;
            var forceMat = false;

            while(AppliedTimes[rndMatIndex] >= 2 || ((randPrevious == rndMatIndex) && !forceMat))
            {
                rndMatIndex = Random.Range(0, _materialList.Count);
                counter++;
                if(counter > 100)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < _materialList.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if(AppliedTimes[j] < 2)
                        {
                            rndMatIndex = j;
                            forceMat = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (forceMat == false)
                        return;
                }

            }

            o.SetFirstMaterial(_firstMaterial, _firstTexturePath);
            o.ApplyFirstMaterial();
            o.SetSecondMaterial(_materialList[rndMatIndex], _texturePathList[rndMatIndex]);
            o.SetIndex(rndMatIndex);
            o.Revealed = false;
            AppliedTimes[rndMatIndex] += 1;
            forceMat = false;
        }


    }

    private void MovePicture(int rows, int columns, Vector2 pos, Vector2 offset)
    {
        var index = 0;
        for(var col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                var targetPosition = new Vector3((pos.x + (offset.x * row)), (pos.y - (offset.y * col)), 0.0f);
                StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(targetPosition, PictureList[index]));
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Vector3 target, Picture obj)
    {
        var randomDis = 7;

        while(obj.transform.position !=target)
        {
            obj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(obj.transform.position, target, randomDis * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your well on your way with the audiosource, and audioclip list. Only need to set your clips sound to the list and shot each when you need how you has done in comented code:  //audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id]).

Comment: thank you Mr joreldraw But when I put `audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id]).` it didn't work!!!

Comment: How i tell you , you need to set your clip list. public List<AudioClip> Vegetabels = new List<AudioClip>(); Vegetabels.add (clip_x);

Comment: no I have put my sounds list but there is an erreur when I put `audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id])`

Comment: You missing the volume scale: audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id] , 1)

Comment: I put it like this
 `public List<AudioClip> Vegetabels = new List<AudioClip>();
    private AudioSource audioSource;`


`if(_revealedPicNumber == 0)
                {
                    _firstRevealedPic = id;
                    _revealedPicNumber++;
                    //audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id], 1);
                } `
But there is an erreur,

Comment: Please attach the error log and show too where you set your clip list with all available clips.

Comment: that's what I put:

--------------------------------------

In definition
`public List<AudioClip> Vegetabels = new List<AudioClip>();

private AudioSource audioSource;`

---------------------------------------

I put `audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id], 1);`
in the (CheckPicture) function, in the for loop.
exactely in :
`if(_revealedPicNumber == 0)
 {
   _firstRevealedPic = id;
   _revealedPicNumber++;
   audioSource.PlayOneShot(Vegetabels[id], 1);
 }`

Comment: the error is :
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PictureManager.CheckPicture () (at Assets/Scripts/PictureManager.cs:133)
Picture+<LoopRotation>d__15.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Picture.cs:113)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <0847a0faf94444ccbaf1958021b27f54>:0)

Comment: You are only creating an empty list of clips. You need to set this list adding clips to not get null reference. 'Vegetabels.add (clip_1);' Vegetabels.add (clip_2); ...etc or attach sounds to the list on inspector.

Comment: yeah,I have attached them on inspector!

Comment: your pictureList.Count match your Vegetabels.Count?

Comment: this is the problem. I don't know how can I match the list of Vegetabls picture and list of Vegetabls sound.

Comment: Your problem is in your pictureList , when you destroy items and deactivated on ienumerator of it. If you like to share i can check in deep your project.